# django-rest-framework: How to prepopulate django-rest-framework serializer fields before validation?

Tags: python, django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

Hello I am new to django and I am using django-rest-framework for making res APIs. Is there any hook or any Signals like django for executing a callback on pre validation state?

I need to prepopulate some data outside the admin area before the validation and then I am doing this stuff:

```
  if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
```

Here is my serializer class:

```
class HeroSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Hero
    fields = ['name', 'alias', 'gender']
```

Do I need another serializer for write operations? or should I create a custom Signal for it? Please suggest me an efficient way to do this.

Comment: Are you asking for some "signal" which modifies the request data before it is passed to your serializer?   What is "pre-validation"?  And yes you should, if at all possible, use a different serializer for create vs list/retrieve. It simplifies things.  From your request here its hard to tell what you want to do.

Comment: @AndrewBacker yes... like is there any signal that can be passed before validation instead of overriding the validation method

Comment: No, there is no signal.